# Angular Js directive update scope value on DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which updates DOM according to mouse-events.

```
<input mask-directive
ui-mask="{{phoneMask}}"
placeholder="{{phonePlaceholder}}"
ui-mask-placeholder
class="form-control input-phone">
```

Directive code is

```
.directive('maskDirective', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            uiMask: '@',
            phonePlaceholder : '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('mouseover', function () {
                scope.uiMask = '999-999-9999';
                scope.phonePlaceholder = '';
            });
            element.on('mouseenter', function () {
                //something
            });
            element.on('mouseleave', function () {
                //something
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Problem is -

```
element.on('mouseover', function () {
    scope.uiMask = '999-999-9999';
    scope.phonePlaceholder = '';
});
```

It is not updating uiMask and phonePlaceholder value on DOM.

Comment: It *is* updating those values.. problem might be where you are using them

Comment: yes it is showing updates on console, I want to use updated values input which is in html

Comment: Is there any watch i have to implement here?

Comment: depends on where/how you use them.. share that code or create a minimal example on plunker maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your code and use angular template and events.

Directive

```
.directive('maskDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            uiMask: '@',
            phonePlaceholder : '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.myFunc = myFunc;

            function myFunc() {
                scope.uiMask = '999-999-9999';
                scope.phonePlaceholder = '';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Element

```
<mask-directive
ui-mask="{{phoneMask}}"
placeholder="{{phonePlaceholder}}"
ui-mask-placeholder>
```

Template myTemplate.html

```
<input ngMouseOver="myFunc()" class="form-control input-phone">
```